# Does to much Wordpress Pages slow down a site with /%postname%/ Permalink structure?

Tags: wordpress

I read this interesting article [So really, don’t use just /%postname%/ as your permalink structure.](http://digwp.com/2011/06/dont-use-postname/)

Im building a new website with over 30 pages (NOT posts!!!). All pages gets by default the permalink structure like "mydomain/p-o-s-t-n-a-m-e". I read a lot of articles and all say the same - "To much pages slow down the site"

Now my Question because im not a database expert:

Does it make sense to start every page with a number in the title?
Like:

"mydoman/0001-p-o-s-t-n-a-m-e"

The sites i created are only to show search results filtert from a spcific wordpress user meta. Not important for SEO or something else to consider the permalink...

Would be awesome if you share your thoughts with me - Thank you so much.

Comment: 30 is not much, that link is 2 years old, So use new WP, do tests, compare. Should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did test with clean WP 3.8 and **500 pages** (not posts) and permalinks /%postname%/ and ?p=123. Result: **no big differences** in total sql queries or load time.

Comment: Hi, thx for your input. Sounds good ;) Does numbers in Front of the title make any difference? I  mean - numbers and after that the title without slash between...

Comment: it should speed MySQL queries a little, but i believe using /00001-post-name/ is not good, better /0001/post-name/